# Laravel: pivot table extra field in model

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Let's assume I've got a User model and the Country model.
User could have up to four countries simultaneously (home country and three countries he'd like to visit).
Using Eloquent, I'd create a pivot able country_user with an extra field of type, that would correspond to the choice of the user, which country he'd put in the first place etc.
So once again, there is:

```
    User
     --id

    Country
     --id

    country_user
     --id
     --user_id
     --country_id
     --type
```

I need to get all users who have, let's say, Canada as a country type 1, UK as a country type 2, France as a country type 3 and New Zealand as a country type 4. If I understand correctly then I can't use wherePivot to do this, only if I get a User::all() and iterate through this collection (which doesn't make much sense and puts unnecessary load on the DB).
What could be the proper way to do this with a minimum possible amount of queries to DB?
Or do I get it all wrong and there should be another approach to this task at all?

Comment: For your described case, it might be better to have a `home_country_id` on `users`, and reserve the `country_user` table for "wishlist" countries (i.e. list of countries they want to visit). You'd define two relationships, `public function homeCountry() { return $this->belongsTo(Country::class, 'home_country_id'); }` and `public function countries() { return $this->hasMany(Country::class); }`. The "type" feels irrelevant for a use-case where only 1 can have a different type than the others (if I understand correctly). Sidenote `pivot` tables generally don't have an `id`, although it's harmless

Answer (score 0):

You can the country relationship of `HasMany`

So, in users it would be this

```
public function countries() {
     return $this->hasMany('country_user_class', 'foreign_key_id_here')->latest()->take(4); // take 4 since the user can have 4 countries
}
```

The query would look something like this.

```
User::whereHas('countries', function($query) {
    $query->where('type', [1,2,3,4]);
})->get();
```

This would give you the result. This is how you can achieve it using Query. Such a problem can always be solved by Query. Let me know if you've any more question regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

You can still search on the `pivot` table using the `relationship` you have defined between a `User` and `Country`. If for the sake of this example we call that relationship `countries` and that you want to find people with the following `$criteria` (sticking to your example):

```php
$criteria = [
    'canada' => 1,
    'uk' => 2,
    'france' => 3,
    'new zealand' => 4,
];
```

So the `key` in the above is the `Country` and the `value` is the `type`.

To find `Users` that have those exact requirements, you could do the following:

```php
$users = User::whereHas('countries');

collect($criteria)->each(function ($type, $country) use ($users) {
    $users->whereHas('countries', function (Builder $query) use ($type, $country) {
        $query->where(['name' => $country, 'type' => $type]);
    })->get();
});
```

Then do something with your `$users`.

```php
$users->get();
```